on default installation Daemon startup failed
I try default "Start project" applications but have problem:
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-8.4.1-11315950-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:193)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:190)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:77)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:100)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$leasingAapt2Daemon$1.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:195)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.compile(PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.kt:47)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnableKt.runAapt2Compile(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:57)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform.transform(AarResourcesCompilerTransform.kt:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransform.transform(DefaultTransform.java:276)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractTransformExecution$2.call(AbstractTransformExecution.java:143)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractTransformExecution$2.call(AbstractTransformExecution.java:137)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractTransformExecution.executeWithinTransformerListener(AbstractTransformExecution.java:137)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractTransformExecution.execute(AbstractTransformExecution.java:130)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:28)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.NoInputChangesStep.execute(NoInputChangesStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.NoInputChangesStep.execute(NoInputChangesStep.java:21)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.NeverUpToDateStep.execute(NeverUpToDateStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.NeverUpToDateStep.execute(NeverUpToDateStep.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:125)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$executeInTemporaryWorkspace$1(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:143)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider$1.withTemporaryWorkspace(CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.executeInTemporaryWorkspace(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:88)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:88)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:23)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:50)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.lambda$executeDeferred$0(IdentityCacheStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.cache.Cache.lambda$get$0(Cache.java:31)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
at org.gradle.cache.ManualEvictionInMemoryCache.get(ManualEvictionInMemoryCache.java:30)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory$CrossBuildCacheRetainingDataFromPreviousBuild.get(DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory.java:255)
at org.gradle.cache.Cache.get(Cache.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.lambda$executeDeferred$1(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.Deferrable$3.completeAndGet(Deferrable.java:117)
... 24 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: Failed to start AAPT2 process.
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopQuietly(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:126)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.startProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:113)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:56)
... 121 more
Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-8.4.1-11315950-windows Daemon #0: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:249)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopQuietly(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:128)
... 123 more
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:320)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:160)
at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:248)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:257)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:239)
... 124 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Process unexpectedly exit.
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.startProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:114)
... 122 more
BUILD FAILED in 31s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
I try different "Start application", different Gradles, reinstall Android Studio.
OS: Windows 11.
